# If a cell with fill color X is changed to no fill color then return the cell fill color to X

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in Excel that contains dates. The table's records are linked to a calendar (on another sheet) so that if you click on a date in the table you will be taken to that date's cell in the calendar. On my calendar sheet I have the following VBA that changes the fill color of the active cell of that sheet to yellow.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cell As Range
    'Turn off ScreenUpdating (speeds up code)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Loop through each cell in the ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        'Check for a specific fill color
        If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then
            'Remove Fill Color
            cell.Interior.Color = xlNone
        End If
    Next cell
    ' Highlight the active cell
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If a user activates another cell on the calendar sheet, that originally contained a fill color, it will clear out that cell's original color.

I would like cells on the sheet that are to be changed by this code from fill color X (purple, in my case) to no fill color, instead remain the fill color X as set by the user.

I basically need fill color layers in Excel.

Comment: Is the default color (x color) for cells always the same?

Comment: Hey Kresimir L. no I am sorry I should have been more specific. There are a total of 3 colors. I can give you the RGBs of each:

Color 1: R-96, G-73, and B-122
Color 2: R-177, G-160, and B-199
Color 3: R-228, G-223, and B-236. It will only ever be those 3

Comment: So from your description it sounds like you want to set the cell back to the color it used to be before it was changed? Is that correct? If it is than you will have to keep track of the cell color and cell address in an array or maybe a hidded sheet and than everytime someone clicks on a cell you will search that array to see if you need to reset the color.

Comment: The first part removes the highlight of the previous selected cell? So the hard part is that you have to remember the initial color and save it somewhere, and know when to put back this initial color.. Maybe you can save all the colors in some hidden rows, and paste them, after removing the previous highlight, and before adding the new highlight

Comment: Yes, that is correct, Miguel. I see what you are saying and I am open to giving that solution a shot. I have not worked with something similar to that so what would I need to do in VBA and on that new hidden sheet to make that happen?

Comment: pk_22 yea you got the gist of it saving that original color is the tricky part. I think Miguel is onto something though using that hidden sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this (i use 2 ranges (a2,a3) to save previous situations you can select any you want:

```
 Option Explicit




Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As String
    Dim i1 As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    i = Range("a3").Value
    i1 = Range("a2").Value


'Turn off ScreenUpdating (speeds up code)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop through each cell in the ActiveSheet
  For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'Check for a specific fill color
      If cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0) Then

        'Remove Fill Color
          cell.Interior.Color = xlNone

      End If

  Next cell

  Range(i).Interior.Color = i1

    ' Highlight the active cell
   ' If Target.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
   Range("a3").Value = Target.Address
   Range("a2").Value = Target.Interior.Color
    Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6

   ' End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance however, that doesn't give me exactly what I am looking for. While it maintains the colors that were previously located on the sheet it does not change those same previously filled cells to yellow when they become active.

Comment: I think this is it! The fill color changes slightly from the original color but I think this will work! I am testing it a little more but it looks great. One thing to note for others is that it only works if you select one cell at I time which is totally fine in my use case.

Comment: Nikolaos Polygenis of course! My bad! This is nearly perfect save for the original colors changing. Any idea on how to fix that? I am still marking it as the answer.

Comment: You are the best!

Comment: I have edited the code, now is perfect!!no difference in colors.please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try using code below. This will work in case you select only one cell at a time. you are using helper cells `M1` & `N1`to store previous cell range and interior color index. since this code is using `ColorIndex` instead or `RGB` values, color in cells will slightly defer from original RGB color, so if possible, try adjusting RGB colors to ColorIndex spectar.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim cell As Range
'Turn off ScreenUpdating (speeds up code)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Range(Range("M1")).Interior.ColorIndex = Range("N1").Value
Range("M1").Value = Target.Address
Range("N1").Value = Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex

' Highlight the active cell
Range("M1").Value = Target.Address
Range("N1").Value = Range(Target.Address).Interior.ColorIndex
Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```